# where to put the state service?

Tags: service

So i'm trying to plan out my services in my 2013 build, in this build i will be doing a tier approach, where as before in my old 2010 design, every thing was on one box.

One of the services i'm scratching my head about is the State Services and where to place it.

I plan to have a couple WFE's and a couple App Servers...the app servers would obviously be hosting the services for the farm.

Should i be putting the state service in the default pool on those app servers or should i be putting it in all pools, regardless WFE or APP server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice is to put each service in its own service application pool.

For the State Service (see more here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704548(v=office.14).aspx) I run it on all of the servers in the farm.  It is meant to temporarily cache objects for web requests, etc., and is more performant if each server has access to it on itself.

Comment: So you create a database for each state service you have?...in example...2 WFE and 2 APP servers...4 databases because you are running state on all 4?

Comment: No, you only need 1 state service and it runs on all the SP servers.

Comment: So if i understand your clarification...you just install it on one server and that takes care of it for the farm, no matter what the scale.

Comment: Correct, a Service Application isn't specific to a server, it's farm wide.  Services on Server is where you choose what runs on each server.

Comment: Got it...mis understood your initial statement. Appreciate your time.